# Lodash - Sort by position in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects

```
let myArray = [
    {
        id: 'first',
        name: 'john',
    },
    {
        id: 'second',
        name: 'Emmy',
    },
    {
        id: 'third',
        name: 'Lazarus',
    }
]
```

and an array

```
let sorter = ['second', 'third', 'first']
```

I would like to use `lodash` sorting method to sort my objects according to their position in `sorter`.
So that the output would be

```
let mySortedArray = [
    {
        id: 'second',
        name: 'Emmy',
    },
    {
        id: 'third',
        name: 'Lazarus',
    },
    {
        id: 'first',
        name: 'john',
    }
]
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fin):

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    id: "first",
    name: "john"
  },
  {
    id: "second",
    name: "Emmy"
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    name: "Lazarus"
  }
];

let sorter = ["second", "third", "first"];

let mySortedArray = sorter.map(x => myArray.find(y => y.id === x));

console.log(mySortedArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using lodash you can use [_.sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy)

```js
let myArray = [
    {
        id: 'first',
        name: 'john',
    },
    {
        id: 'second',
        name: 'Emmy',
    },
    {
        id: 'third',
        name: 'Lazarus',
    }
]

let sorter = ['second', 'third', 'first']

console.log(_.sortBy(myArray,(i) => {return sorter.indexOf(i.id)}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was me not approving cloudflare in umatrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the array in-place, you don't need Lodash, you can easily do it with vanilla JavaScript

```js
let myArray = [
    {
        id: 'first',
        name: 'john',
    },
    {
        id: 'second',
        name: 'Emmy',
    },
    {
        id: 'third',
        name: 'Lazarus',
    }
]

let sorter = ['second', 'third', 'first']

//create a lookup table (map) to save looking through the array
const sortLookup = new Map(); 
//populate with element as key - index as value
sorter.forEach((id, index) => sortLookup.set(id, index));

//sort using the indexes of sorter 
myArray.sort((a, b) => sortLookup.get(a.id) - sortLookup.get(b.id))

console.log(myArray)
```

This is using [a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) but the same can easily be accomplished with a plain JavaScript Object `{}`. You don't even need to pre-compute the lookup `myArray.sort((a, b) => sorter.indexOf(a.id) - sorter.indexOf(b.id))` would give the exact same output but it would mean that instead of traversing `sorter` once for a complexity of `O(n)`, you potentially have `O(n^m)`or `O(n^n)` (if both arrays are the same length)

Comment: This is exactly what I was using, unfortunately, the `sort` methods behaves differently from one browser to the other, resulting in different sorted arrays. Therefore, using lodash (or any other method that doesn't rely on `sort`) would solve this issue

Comment: Yes - different browsers do use different sorting algorithms. However, you shouldn't actually be getting different results - the algorithm of choice would still produce the same order, as long as the comparator provides consistent results. If you tried returning *logically different* values for the same comparison (e.g., `compare(a, b)` -> 1 `compare(b, a)` -> 0), then that's inconsistent and you are breaking the sorting interface. The only other issue is that sorting is not necessarily stable - do you items that are equal (according to the comparator) that you still need in specific order?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `index` array in the case of the `sorter` you can [**`_.keyBy`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy) the main array and then use the `sorter` to access by index:

```js
let myArray = [ { id: 'first', name: 'john', }, { id: 'second', name: 'Emmy', }, { id: 'third', name: 'Lazarus', } ]
let sorter = ['second', 'third', 'first']

const idMap = _.keyBy(myArray, 'id')
const result = _.map(sorter, x => idMap[x])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This should perform better since you only do the `idMap once` and then `access it by index`.